# Magento 2 - Custom Currencies

Tags: currency, magento2, locale

A cursory review of some classes in the Magento 2 codebase seems like the core devs do not intend to change how currencies are architected in the new version. Shouldn't this be reconsidered in light of the growing popularity of virtual currencies (Bitcoin, Litecoin, etc)?

It seems that adding a new currency to the system shouldn't involve modifications to `/lib/Zend` or other core files, but this appears to be the case. Imagine the nightmares you'd experience trying to allow users of your store to make purchases with just a small number of virtual currencies - those modules are going to be walking all over each other!

Also of note is the practice of having currency/locale/language all so tighly coupled.

Are store owners/developers going to have to continue resorting to core file hacks to use virtual currencies? Are there any plans to modify the architecture to make implementing new virtual currencies more manageable?

Comment: I asked about decoupling locale from scope, was told "nope" :-(

Comment: That's quite unfortunate. Was it simply a "nope" or did they provide some justification?

Comment: I would like to understand more about the issue you are facing.
so to rephrase - you want to be able to set any currency (real or virtual) in the way it won't affect the client modules? and also decouple locale from the stores, so you can register a few languages in the system and then assign them to the different store views? did I understand you correctly? Am I missing smth?

Answer (score 2):

It can't find my comment, but [here's something relevant from Magento core team](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/223#issuecomment-13677001):

> *The language management definitely could be improved and we want to take care of it but it is not on our short term roadmap. Sharing languages across stores or language inheritance would help a lot. That being said we encourage you to try to implement it - however it might get pretty big.*